# Exponential complex numbers question

Tags: complex-numbers

**Find all solutions of $\mathbf{e^{4z}= −3 − 3i}$**

I'm having a bit of trouble with the question above. I started out with $4z= \ln(-3-3i)$ but I don't know where to go from here.

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean $e^{4z}=-3-3i$?

Comment: Yes I'm new to this site I don't know how to format everything yet.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: $\ln z=\ln (|z|e^{i\arg z})=\ln |z|+i\arg z +2\pi i k$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of facts to bear in mind.

- The complex exponential function is periodic, with period $2\pi i$.
- $|e^{x+iy}|=|e^x||e^{iy}|=e^x\cdot1=e^x$

Now $|-3-3i|=\sqrt{3^2+3^2}=\sqrt{18},$ so $e^x=\sqrt{18}$

If we divide both sides of $e^{x+iy}$ by $e^x,$ we get $e^{iy}=-\frac12-\frac12 i$ which has the solution $y=-{\pi\over4}$.

Therefore, $z=\frac12\ln{18}+i({\pi\over4}+2n\pi), n=0,\pm 1\pm 2,\dots$

Comment: Thank you very much! This really helps

Answer (score 0):

We have for $$z=x+iy$$so $$e^{4(x+iy)}=e^{4x}\cos(4y)+ie^{4x}\sin(4y)=-3-3i$$ so we get
$$e^{4x}\cos(4y)=-3$$ and $$e^{4x}\sin(4y)=-3$$
So we have $$\tan(4y)=1$$